# Audio file spectrogram, is it time vs amplitude or time vs frequency?

Tags: audio, spectrogram

When I am trying to create an spectrogram of an audio file, should I plot time vs amplitude or time vs frequency ?

Answer (score 5):

All three. One axis is time, one axis is frequency, and the third axis (or color or brightness or whatever) is the intensity of that frequency at that time, as determined by a fourier transform.

Comment: Yep. Although when I want to create a spectrogram for an audio file (like what www.soundcloud.com uses in their player) what do i use, because the normal spectrograms we find are just 2-d images.

Comment: Soundcloud doesn't have a spectrogram anywhere I can see.

Comment: I guess I meant an amplitude waveform (e.g. http://soundcloud.com/dawnbrian5/photograph-katie-by-brian-clayton)